# get the column name by given value in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the table `geo` with fields `'us','uk','india','china'`
I want to get the column name which has the value '1'

[image]

If I give the `sno` 1 I want to get india which has the value `1` and for `sno` 2 I want to get `us` and `china`
How to get the column name by the value and sno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a strange database design, but can be achieved by converting the row to a JSON value. With that it's possible to iterate over the column names and pick those that have the value 1

```
select (select string_agg(col, ', ' order by col) 
        from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(geo) - 'sno') t(col, val)
        where t.val = '1')
from geo
where sno = ...;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=59e4a6dea7ba5f313b625db453b9f29a)

Comment: how to use this in laravel